# Delete duplicate records based on multiple columns and remain with one in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have the below code with columns UnitRateID, UnitOwnerID,TelecomID, CommType, DATE(Timestamp), Message which helps me identify if something is a duplicate record within a period.
The code works absolutely amazing.

```
Select UnitRateID, UnitOwnerID,TelecomID, CommType, DATE(Timestamp), Message
From Communication
WHERE DATE(`Timestamp`)>= '2020-04-06'
Having (UnitRateID)>1
```

I now want to delete the duplicate records and remain with one.
I tried the following but it does not work at all.

```
Delete From Communication AS C1 
WHERE EXISTS (Select 1
from Communication As C2
WHERE C1.UnitRateID=C2.UnitRateID
AND C1.UnitOwnerID=C2.UnitOwnerID 
AND C1.TelecomID=C2.TelecomID
AND C1.CommType=C2.CommType
AND C1.Message=C2.Message
AND C1.Timestamp> C2.Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `JOIN`:

```
Delete c
    From Communication c JOIN
         (select UnitRateID, UnitOwnerID, TelecomID, CommType, Message,
                 min(Timestamp) as min_Timestamp
          from Communication c
          group by UnitRateID, UnitOwnerID, TelecomID, CommType, Message
         ) c2
         on c.UnitRateID = C2.UnitRateID and
            c.UnitOwnerID = C2.UnitOwnerID and
            c.TelecomID = C2.TelecomID and
            c.CommType = C2.CommType and
            c.Message = C2.Message
            c.Timestamp > C2.min_Timestamp;
```